# How do you update the levels of a pandas MultiIndex after slicing its DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with a pandas MultiIndex:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['CAN','USA'],['total']],names=['country','sex'])
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'pop':[35,318]},index=multi_index)
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
               pop
country sex
CAN     total   35
USA     total  318
```

Then I remove some rows from that DataFrame:

```
In [5]: df = df.query('pop > 100')

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
               pop
country sex
USA     total  318
```

But when I consult the MutliIndex, it still has both countries in its levels.

```
In [7]: df.index.levels[0]
Out[7]: Index([u'CAN', u'USA'], dtype='object')
```

I can fix this myself in a rather strange way:

```
In [8]: idx_names = df.index.names

In [9]: df = df.reset_index(drop=False)

In [10]: df = df.set_index(idx_names)

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
               pop
country sex
USA     total  318

In [12]: df.index.levels[0]
Out[12]: Index([u'USA'], dtype='object')
```

But this seems rather messy. Is there a better way I'm missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is something that has bitten me before. Dropping columns or rows does NOT change the underlying MultiIndex, for performance and philosophical reasons, and this is officially not considered a bug ([read more here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3686)). The short answer is that the developers say "that's not what the MultiIndex is for". If you need a list of the contents of a MultiIndex level after modification, for example for iteration or to check to see if something is included, you can use:

```
df.index.get_level_values(<levelname>)
```

This returns the current active values within that index level.

So I guess the "trick" here is that the API native way to do it is to use get_level_values instead of just .index or .columns

Comment: Oh, and you can add .unique() to that if you don't want repeats. The default level values include each occurance so you'll see a lot of duplicates in a typical multi-index scenario

Comment: You can also use `unique(data.index.values)` to get values across all levels.

Answer (score 21):

From version [`pandas 0.20.0+`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-shown-levels) use [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html):

```
print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['CAN', 'USA'], ['total']],
           labels=[[1], [0]],
           names=['country', 'sex'])

df.index = df.index.remove_unused_levels()

print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['USA'], ['total']],
           labels=[[0], [0]],
           names=['country', 'sex'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I will be surprised if there is a more "built-in" way to eliminate the unused country than to re-create the index in the way you're doing (or some similar way). If you look at your index before and after the slice:

```
In [165]: df.index
Out[165]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'CAN', u'USA'], [u'total']],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 0]],
           names=[u'country', u'sex'])

In [166]: df = df.query('pop > 100')

In [167]: df.index
Out[167]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'CAN', u'USA'], [u'total']],
           labels=[[1], [0]],
           names=[u'country', u'sex'])
```

you can see that the labels - which are indexes into the level values - have updated but not the level values. This may be an imperfect analogy, but it strikes me that the level values are analogous to an enumerated column in a database table, while the labels are analogous to the actual values of rows in the table. If you delete all the rows in a table with a value of "CAN", it doesn't change the fact that "CAN" is still a valid choice based on the column definition. To remove "CAN" from the enumeration, you have to alter the column definition; this is the equivalent of reindexing the dataframe in pandas.