# How to prevent pandas DataFrame from retaining the full index after subsetting?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex`.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': np.arange(5)}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 'a'), ('A', 'b'), ('B', 'c'), ('B', 'd'), ('C', 'e')]))
[Out]:
       var1
A   a   0
    b   1
B   c   2
    d   3
C   e   4
```

If I subset it, it'll retain the full index (even when I use `.copy()`)

```
df2.loc[['A', 'C']].copy().index
[Out]: MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 4]])
```

What's the rationale behind this behavior? How to prevent this from happening? I expect the new index to only include `[['A', 'C'], ['a', 'b', 'e']`.

Comment: Related, although slightly different IMO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772494/how-do-you-update-the-levels-of-a-pandas-multiindex-after-slicing-its-dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`remove_unused_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html#pandas-multiindex-remove-unused-levels).

```
df = df2.loc[['A', 'C']].copy()
df.index = df.index.remove_unused_levels()
df.index
```

Output:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'C'], ['a', 'b', 'e']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: As of pandas 0.20.0

Comment: Okay, so the syntax for that old solution was completely wrong.  That is what I get for trying to answer a SO post on my phone without testing it first.   Thanks.