# Pandas DataFrame MultiIndex column/index level entries remain after slicing. How to remove them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Say I take a subsection of a 9-column `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex` columns as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('a','b','c'),('x','y','z')])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,9), columns=columns)
dfs = df[['a','b']]
print(dfs.columns, '\n', ('c' in dfs))
```

The print statement yields

```
True
MultiIndex(levels=[['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']], 
    labels=[[0,0,0,1,1,1],[0,1,2,0,1,2]])
```

...so after taking the subsection, 'c' still appears in the **first level** of the column `MultiIndex` object, and calling `'c' in dfs` will yield `True`. However, the `labels` attribute of the `MultiIndex` object are changed.

How can I make pandas **delete the unused level entries** when a `MultiIndex`ed `DataFrame` is sliced like this? I am passing `DataFrame`s between functions that iterate over every column, and would like to prevent iterating over the empty columns.

---

**Update**: A more general problem was solved with a recent pandas update, but this more specific problem remains in the most recent version.

Comment: Cannot reproduce... I'm getting `Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object') False`

Comment: I think this was one of the fixed bugs. What version are you using?

Comment: @ayhan That was the problem, thanks!

Comment: @ayhan
@juanpa.arrivillaga you guys were right, but a similar/more specific problem is still present for `MultiIndex` columns/indexes.

Comment: For the updated version: this is also a known issue but as far as I remember they have decided to keep this as it is. Instead, they added [remove_unused_levels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html)  See [jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43824296/2285236) for its usage.

Comment: Thanks! Will mark this thread as duplicate.